Question Regarding Building .Net Maui Apps For Mac x64 And Mac Arm
I am very new to Maui and would like to know if when building a Net Maui App For Mac x64 And Mac Arm, do I have to build each one on their respective platform?
For example:
Build the Mac X64 on an Intel Mac
Build the Mac Arm on a mac Arm machine
I have tried to build the project using dotnet build in VScode which does create both arm64 and x64 Releases but when I run the Arm64 app on a Mac M1 it just crashes but if I compile the same code on a Mac M1 it runs fine.
